# How can I transfer data between one jframe to another jframe?

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I'm new to java and for some reason I don't know any other way to transfer the data from another frame after pressing submit. For example, it will show the output frame the label and textfield that the user wrote in the first frame like this "Name: "user's name". If you do know please post the code I should put, thank you!

```
package eventdriven;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EventDriven extends JFrame {
    
    JPanel items = new JPanel();
    
    JLabel fName = new JLabel("First Name: ");
    JLabel lName = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
    JLabel mName = new JLabel("Middle Name: ");
    JLabel mNum = new JLabel("Mobile Number: ");
    JLabel eAdd = new JLabel("Email Address: ");
    
    JTextField fname = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField lname = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField mname = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField mnum = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField eadd = new JTextField(15);

    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear All");
    JButton okay = new JButton("Okay");
    
    JTextArea infos;
    JFrame output;
    
    public EventDriven()
    {
        this.setTitle("INPUT");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(230, 300);
        this.setLocation(300, 300);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       
        this.add(fName);
        this.add(fname);
        this.add(lName);
        this.add(lname);
        this.add(mName);
        this.add(mname);
        this.add(mNum);
        this.add(mnum);
        this.add(eAdd);
        this.add(eadd);
       
        submit.addActionListener(new btnSubmit());
        this.add(submit);
        clear.addActionListener(new btnClearAll());
        this.add(clear);
        okay.addActionListener(new btnOkay());
        
        
        this.add(items);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    class btnSubmit implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getSource() == submit)
            {
            submit.setEnabled(false);
            output = new JFrame("OUTPUT");
            output.show();
            output.setSize(300,280);
            output.setTitle("OUTPUT");
           
            
            output.add(okay);
            output.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            }   
        }
    }
    
    class btnClearAll implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getSource() == clear)
            {
                fname.setText(null);
                lname.setText(null);
                mname.setText(null);
                mnum.setText(null);
                eadd.setText(null);
                submit.setEnabled(true);
                output.dispose();
            }
        }   
    }
    
    class btnOkay implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getSource() == okay)
            {
                fname.setText(null);
                lname.setText(null);
                mname.setText(null);
                mnum.setText(null);
                eadd.setText(null);
                submit.setEnabled(true);
                output.dispose();
            }
        }    
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        EventDriven window = new EventDriven();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Consider using a [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for the second window (rather than `JFrame`).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what problem you are having displaying a value from one field in another frame. But here's an example of doing that (with fields reduced to just one for demonstration):

```
public class EventDriven extends JFrame {
    private final JTextField nameField = new JTextField(15);
    private final JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    private final JButton clear = new JButton("Clear All");

    public EventDriven() {
        setTitle("Input");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new JLabel("Name: "));
        add(nameField);
        submit.addActionListener(this::showOutput);
        add(submit);
        clear.addActionListener(this::clearInput);
        add(clear);
        pack();
    }

    private void showOutput(ActionEvent ev) {
        submit.setEnabled(false);
        JDialog output = new JDialog(EventDriven.this, "Output", true);
        output.add(new Label("Name: " + nameField.getText()), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        output.add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        okButton.addActionListener(bv -> output.setVisible(false));
        output.pack();
        output.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void clearInput(ActionEvent ev) {
        nameField.setText(null);
        submit.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventDriven window = new EventDriven();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You will also see that I've simplified your action listeners to demonstrate an easier way to respond to user driven event.s

Comment: I wanted to get a result just like yours in output frame which would display the text only instead of mine appearing like the same as input frame. Would it be possible to do it in the code I've posted?